# Object properties in List overwritten on each iteration

Tags: c#

I have constructed the following simplistic example to illustrate the problem I'm having in my actual code, which is much more complex.

First, my simple classes:

```
public class InnerTemp {
   public int A { get; set; }
   public int B { get; set; }
   public int C { get; set; }
}

public class OuterTemp {
   public List<InnerTemp> InnerTemps { get; set; }
}
```

And the implementation:

```
var outerTemps = new List<OuterTemp>();
var innerTemps = new List<InnerTemp>();
innerTemps.Add(new InnerTemp() { A = 1, B = 2, C = 3 });
innerTemps.Add(new InnerTemp() { A = 4, B = 5, C = 6 });

for( int i = 1; i < 5; i++ ) {
      foreach( InnerTemp innerTemp in innerTemps ) {
           innerTemp.A += i;
           innerTemp.B += i;
           innerTemp.C += i;
       }

       var outerTemp = new OuterTemp()
       {
           InnerTemps = innerTemps
       };

       outerTemps.Add(outerTemp);
}
```

I set my breakpoint on the last line, the closing curly brace. On the first iteration, the value of `outerTemps[0].InnerTemps[0].A` is 2, as expected. But on the 2nd loop, the value of `outerTemps[0].InnerTemps[0].A` becomes 4, which is baffling me. The first object's property A is being stomped merely because another object was added. I fully expect `outerTemps[1].InnerTemps[0].A` to be different, but why is my original property stomped?

How can I change this so that previous object properties don't get overwritten each time a new object is added to the collection?

Comment: What would you want `outerTemps[0].InnerTemps[0].A` to be on the second loop?

Comment: You should take a look at [shallow vs deep copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy). You are copying a reference to `innerTemps` instead of doing a deep copy of all the elements. This causes the same InnertTemp reference to be modified for each outerTemp object.

Comment: Its obvious that you are modifying the same list in each of the iteration. You need to create a new list of InnerTemp with deep copy of all the objects in it on each iteration of outer for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment you are creating a shallow copy of the `innerTemps` list which causes the references to be copied instead of creating deep copies of each `InnerTemp` object in the list.

If you want to have separate `InnerTemp` objects in the newly created `OuterTemp` that are tracked and modified separately, you have to create a deep copy of them.

Per the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78856/2562283) I would recommend creating a `Copy` method on your `InnerTemp` class:

```
public class InnerTemp
{
   public int A { get; set; }
   public int B { get; set; }
   public int C { get; set; }

   public static InnerTemp Copy(InnerTemp source)
   {
      return new InnerTemp { A = source.A, B = source.B, C = source.C };
   }
}
```

And use that when creating the new list for each `OuterTemp`:

```
var outerTemp = new OuterTemp()
{
    InnerTemps = innerTemps.Select(InnerTemp.Copy).ToList();
};
```

This will prevent the values in the `outerTemps` list from being modified by the loop counter. Note that the `.ToList()` implicitly creates a deep copy by evaluating the `Select` enumerable and returning a new list, so you don't have to worry about the list references causing problems.

Comment: Thanks for that Moffat.